# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' " While creating an age converter?

Tags: python, math, converters

Does anybody have the slightest clue why this won't work? (Click link to see print screen)

http://prntscr.com/5tbfos

I'd be especially appreciative if you were to fix it for me!

Thanks In Advance,

Ben Johnson

Comment: In general, try to inline code samples into your question on StackOverflow.  Perhaps you could have what you feel is the most relevant section on this website and retain a link to the full source as well.

Comment: I guess that would work as expected with Python 2.7, but you're using Python 3.x... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/input-integers-python.

Answer (score 2):

`input` returns a string. And a string can't be equal to an integer. `if PetAge==1` is wrong also other parts too because you can **not** do calculates with a string. You have to write;

```
PetAge= int(input("blabla"))
```

Here how your program should be;

```
if pet=="cat":
    PetAge=int(input("Enter your cat age"))
    if PetAge==1:
        print ("blabla")
    elif PetAge==2:
        print ("morebla")
    else:
        CatAge=(PetAge-2)+25+4
        print ("Your cat is {} cat years old".format(CatAge))
```

Also remember;

```
"26" != 26
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some ideas on how to divide your program into functions to make it easier to think about.

```
def get_int(prompt):
    """
    Prompt user to input an integer value

    Loop until a good value is entered,
      then return the value
    """
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            # couldn't convert to int - try again
            pass

def cat_age(age):
    """
    Convert human years to cat years
    """
    if age == 1:
        return 15
    elif age == 2:
        return 25
    else:
        return 25 + (age - 2) * 4

# A more advanced technique:
#   a function that creates a function!
def make_age_function(given_ages, rate):
    num = len(given_ages)
    last = given_ages[-1] if num else 0
    def age_function(age):
        """
        Given an age in years, calculate human-equivalent age
        """
        if age < num:
            return given_ages[age - 1]
        else:
            return last + (age - num) * rate
    return age_function

# Now let's use it to make a dog_age function:
dog_age = make_age_function([15, 25], 4)
# dog_age gives exactly the same results as cat_age

# How about a turtle_age function?
turtle_age = make_age_function([], 0.45)

# We need to keep track of which pets
#   we know how to convert ages for
known_pets = {
    "cat":    cat_age,
    "dog":    dog_age,
    "turtle": turtle_age
}

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Pet Age Converter")
    while True:
        print("What kind of pet do you have? (or hit Enter to exit)")
        pet = input().strip().lower()

        if pet in known_pets:
            age = get_int("What is your {}'s age? ".format(pet))
            # look up the appropriate age converter function
            age_fn = known_pets[pet]
            # and use it to calculate pet age
            pet_age = age_fn(age)
            # now show the results
            print("Your {} is {} {} years old.".format(pet, pet_age, pet))
        elif pet:
            print("I didn't know anyone had a {}!".format(pet))
        else:
            # exit the while loop
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```